# getting System.InvalidOperationException: Listbox DataSource VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

This is the error I am getting

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.'
```

I have a Listbox that is databound The list of items are stored days table the saved value is stored in a record table. The List is a Comma Separated List E.G: 1,2,3,4,5
Would equate to Items with values of 1 -5 being selected on load.

This is the save Routine which Works perfectly

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.Leave
    Dim listboxItems As New List(Of String)

    For Each row As DataRowView In ListBox1.SelectedItems
        listboxItems.Add(row("IDNum"))

    Next row
    selectLoad = True
    lblDays.Text = String.Join(",", listboxItems.ToArray())

End Sub
```

This is Routine Which is Throwing the error.

```
Private Sub BGWLoadData_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BGWLoadData.RunWorkerCompleted

        Dim TextBoxStrings() As String = {""}


    Try
        Dim TempStr() As String = lblDays.Text.Split(",")
        ReDim TextBoxStrings(TempStr.Count - 1)
        TextBoxStrings = TempStr
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Dim TextBoxDoubles(TextBoxStrings.Count - 1) As Double
    For a As Integer = 0 To TextBoxStrings.Count - 1
        Try
            TextBoxDoubles(a) = TextBoxStrings(a)
        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBoxDoubles(a) = 0
        End Try
    Next

    Do While DaysBound = False
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    ListBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()
    Dim TempIndex As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataRowView In ListBox1.Items
        For a As Integer = 0 To TextBoxDoubles.Count - 1
            If row("IDNum") = TextBoxDoubles(a) Then
                ListBox1.SetSelected(TempIndex, True)
            End If
        Next
        TempIndex = TempIndex + 1
    Next row
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong or what can be done to make the code more efficient.

Edit:
Error Occurs at Next Row.
Also telling me I have done something wrong isn't helpful I know something is Wrong because I am getting errors. I am asking for is how to fix this with a code snippet or something.

Comment: You cannot change a list while looping on that list. Make a copy and assign the resulting list after the loop.

Comment: I am not trying to change the list at all.

It should be Reading the list, and then setting the selected items for the values it has.

Comment: VS seems to disagree with you.  As for the last part, you should turn on Option Strict, dont use empty Catch blocks, dont use Try/Catch for program flow control, dont use DoEvents.  Dont glue the values together if you know you will need them separately later.  Read [ask] and take the [tour] and dont make us guess where the exception is thrown - tell us the line.

Answer (score 0):

This Has been Solved by Adding a second arrary

```
If selectLoad = False Then

        ' convert CSV of IDNums of selected items in listbox into string array
        Dim TextBoxStrings() As String = {""}
        Try
            Dim TempStr() As String = lblDays.Text.Split(",")
            ReDim TextBoxStrings(TempStr.Count - 1)
            TextBoxStrings = TempStr
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        ' convert string array to double array
        Dim TextBoxDoubles(TextBoxStrings.Count - 1) As Double
        For a As Integer = 0 To TextBoxStrings.Count - 1
            Try
                TextBoxDoubles(a) = TextBoxStrings(a)
            Catch ex As Exception
                TextBoxDoubles(a) = -1
            End Try
        Next

        ' load underlying IDNums into temporary array
        Dim TempIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim TempIDNums(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As Integer
        For Each row As DataRowView In ListBox1.Items
            TempIDNums(TempIndex) = row("IDNum")
            TempIndex = TempIndex + 1
        Next row

        ' if any of the underlying IDNums are found in the CSV, select that item in the listbox
        ListBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()
        For ListItemCounter As Integer = 0 To TempIDNums.Count - 1
            For SelectedItemCounter As Integer = 0 To TextBoxDoubles.Count - 1
                If TempIDNums(ListItemCounter) = TextBoxDoubles(SelectedItemCounter) Then
                    ListBox1.SetSelected(ListItemCounter, True)
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
```